# Не работает библиотека

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте, учусь подключать библиотеки, пока не очень получается, поэтому обратился за советом к вам=)Остановил свой выбор на этой простенькой библиотеке [ссылка на гитхаб](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos). Насколько я понял, то нужно просто подключить скрипты, стили и добавить к элементу такой атрибут data-aos="animation_name", что я и сделал, но ничего не работает. Может вы подскажите, что я сделал не так? Прилагаю свой простенький макет, может тут ошибка.

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header{
  background-color: #6C8AD5;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

header div h1{
  color: white;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #FFC040;
}

.item{
  background-color: #FFD173;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Пример</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/aos/dist/aos.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
 <div><h1>Пробная страница</h1></div>
 </header>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
 </div>
 

 <!-- JS SECTION -->
 <script src="bower_components/aos/dist/aos.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: скорее всего у вас ошибка в пути к файлу `bower_components/aos/dist/aos.js`. Какую ошибку пишет в консоли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере нужно исправить несколько вещей:

**№1** Проверить, что `aos.css` и `aos.js` загружаются - они должны быть либо в папке с вашим проектом и подключаться локально, либо подключаться через CDN:

```
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.0.4/dist/aos.css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.0.4/dist/aos.js">
```

**№2** Проставить для блоков data-aos атрибуты, например так:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-aos="zoom-out-left">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-aos="zoom-out-down">
    <h1>2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-aos="zoom-out-right">
    <h1>3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**№3** Инициализировать AOS - для этого напишите js-файле с вашими скриптами:

```
AOS.init();
```

Или добавьте в вашу верстку тег `<script>`:

```
<script>
  AOS.init();
</script>
```

Тогда все заработает. Рабочий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/0L7vyz4v/